# Angular 2 Inject int to a service, and then inject the service to anther service

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I have two components and three services go like:

- team-chooses-cards.component
- chooses-cards-display.component
- chooses-cards.service
- http-chooses-cards.service
- http-team-chooses-cards.service

The `chooses-cards-display.component` provide him self with `chooses-cards.service` , and `chooses-cards.service` get a `http-chooses-cards.service` by dependency injection.

**chooses-cards-display.component**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ChoosesCardsService} from './Services/chooses-cards.service';
import {ICard} from './Commons/ICard.interface';

@
Component({
    selector: 'chooses-cards-display',
    templateUrl: './templates/ChooseCardComponent/choose-card-display.tpl.html',
    providers: [ChoosesCardsService]
})
export class ChooseCardDisplayComponent {
    private _cards: Array<ICard>;
    public _amount: number;
    public _skip: number; 

    constructor(private _choosesCardService: ChoosesCardsService) {
        this._amount = 3;
        this._skip = 0;
        this._cards = new Array<ICard>();
        this._choosesCardService.getChoosesCards(this._amount, this._skip).forEach(card => {
            console.log("CCDC hi!", card);
            this._cards.push(card);
            console.log("CCDC bye!");
        });
    }
}
```

**chooses-cards.service**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {HttpChoosesCardsService} from './http-chooses-cards.service';
import {HttpUserService} from '../../global/global.services';
import {IUser} from '../../Global/global.commons';
import {ICard} from '../Commons/ICard.interface';
import {CardFactory} from '../Commons/CardFactory.class'


@Injectable()

export class ChoosesCardsService {
    constructor(private _httpChoosesCardsSrvice: HttpChoosesCardsService, private _httpUserSrvice: HttpUserService) {
    }

    getChoosesCards(amount: number, skip: number): Array<ICard> {
        var ret = new Array<ICard>();
        this._httpChoosesCardsSrvice.getChoosesCards(amount, skip).forEach(cardInfo => {
            console.log("CCS hi: ", CardFactory.create(this._httpUserSrvice.getUserById(cardInfo.userId), cardInfo.projectName,
                cardInfo.description, cardInfo.likes));
            ret.push(CardFactory.create(this._httpUserSrvice.getUserById(cardInfo.userId), cardInfo.projectName,
                cardInfo.description, cardInfo.likes));
            console.log("CCS bye!");
        });
        return ret;
    }
}
```

**http-chooses-cards.service**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {ICard} from '../Commons/ICard.interface';

@Injectable()
export abstract class HttpChoosesCardsService {
    abstract getChoosesCards(amount: number, skip: number): any ;
}
```

The `http-chooses-cards.service` is an abstract class, and I provided to `chooses-cards.service` an extends of it called `http-team-chooses-cards.service`.

**http-team-chooses-cards.service**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {HttpChoosesCardsService} from './http-chooses-cards.service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpTeamChoosesCardsService extends HttpChoosesCardsService{

    constructor(private _teamID: number) { super(); console.log("from teamService ", this._teamID);}

    getChoosesCards(amount: number, skip: number): any {
        //Mock data.
        var ret = new Array<any>();
        ret.push({
            "userId": 12,
            "projectName": "Bama",
            "description": "Bama is good",
            "likes" : 100
        });
        ret.push({
            "userId": 2,
            "projectName": "Bama2",
            "description": "Bama2 is Bad",
            "likes": 5
        });
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I provide this service at `team-chooses-cards.component` that loud the `chooses-cards-display.component`.

**team-chooses-cards.component**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {HttpTeamChoosesCardsService} from './Services/http-team-chooses-cards.service';
import {HttpChoosesCardsService} from './Services/http-chooses-cards.service';
import {ChooseCardDisplayComponent} from './chooses-cards-display.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'team-chooses-cards',
    template: `<chooses-cards-display></chooses-cards-display>`,
    directives: [ChooseCardDisplayComponent],
    inputs: ['teamID : given_teamID'],
    providers: [provide(HttpChoosesCardsService, { useClass: HttpTeamChoosesCardsService, useValue: this.teamID})]
})
export class TeamChooseCardComponent {
    @Input('given_teamID') teamID: number;
    constructor() {
        console.log("from teamcomponeny ", this.teamID);
    }
}
```

First, if my logic is wrong, I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me a different way or better architecture, and if not I would be happy if to responses about the architecture.

Now I want to inject a number to the `http-team-chooses-cards.service` when I provide it in the `team-chooses-cards.component`.

Can anyone find what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: is it some kind of puzzle like `how much wood-would a woodchuck-chuck if a woodchuck-could-chuck-wood` , m sorry but m confused

Comment: I wand a chooses-cards-display.component that use a chooses-cards.service that use a http-chooses-cards.service. Now I want to inject the http-team-chooses-cards.service instead of the http-chooses-cards.service. I do it in the team-chooses-cards.component, got it?

Comment: don't take me seriously. if I don't someone else will. PS: I'm going for maditation.  ;) lol